# Java NIO ByteBuffer, write after flip

Tags: java, byte, buffer, nio

I'm new to Java ByteBuffers and was wondering what the correct way to write to a ByteBuffer after it has been flipped.

In my use case, I am writing an outputBuffer to a socket:

```
    outBuffer.flip();
    //Non-blocking SocketChannel
    int bytesWritten = getSocket().write(outBuffer);
```

After this, the output buffer has to be written to again. Also not all of the bytes in the outBuffer may have been written to the socket.

Since it is currently flipped, how can I make it writable again, without overriding any data if it is still in the buffer and wasn't written to the socket?

If I am right, outBuffer.position() == bytesWritten and limit should be at how much data there was to write.

So would using the following in order to reuse the output buffer be right? :

```
   int limit = outBuffer.limit()  
   outBuffer.limit(outBuffer.capacity());
   outBuffer.position(limit);
```

Comment: Do you want to write the entire contents of the (flipped) buffer before reusing it?

Comment: That is a good question. I figured `getSocket().write()` would write as much as it could at the current time, and don't know if it would be worthwhile polling to write the whole buffer or not. For this example, I am just writing as much as the socket allows (`bytesWritten`) and then want to continue putting into the buffer after that,without overwriting any data that wasn't written to the socket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Again* from the API spec.:
**The following loop copies bytes from one channel to another via the buffer buf:**

```
while (in.read(buf) >= 0 || buf.position != 0) {
   buf.flip();
   out.write(buf);
   buf.compact();    // In case of partial write
}
```

Comment: So use `compact` ? Ill take a look at that thanks! Is this a common question or something? I couldn't find anything on google !

Comment: AFAIU this is the right way - but, let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: This is the correct way. Note that it caters correctly for the case where there is still data left to write after the reads have reached end of stream: in other words, if there are short writes, both by using `compact()` and by the double condition. Note also that the loop is really only correct for blocking mode. In non-blocking mode you would only read when there is an OP_READ event.

Comment: This is nice, I don't think I knew about `compact()`, I always just did that step manually.

Answer (score 3):

> since it is currently flipped

It will stay flipped. The write doesn't change that.

> how can I make it writable again, without overriding any data if it is still in the buffer and wasn't written to the socket?

You don't have to do anything, but if you want to read before you write again you should do flip/write/compact. If you just want to repeat the write just call `write()` again, with the buffer still in its current state.

But I prefer to always keep these buffers ready for *reading*, so there is no possibility of a slip-up, and to flip/write/compact (or flip/get/compact) when those operations are necessary, atomically as it were.

Note that you should *not* use `clear()`, unless you are certain that the write was complete and the buffer is now empty. In that case compact and clear are equivalent. But it is simpler to just always compact.

If you're copying in blocking mode, use the loop quoted by @zlakad.