# Java - Read from InputStream to ByteBuffer by chunk size

Tags: android, inputstream, bytebuffer, cronet

I am using Cronet API with our current API stack, specifically [UploadDataProvider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/cronet/reference/org/chromium/net/UploadDataProvider.html#read(org.chromium.net.UploadDataSink,%20java.nio.ByteBuffer)), there is a ByteBuffer with preset limit, seems like the limit size is fixed and we need to pass the data chunk by chunk. Our current API uses InputStream, and write chunk to OutputStream. We're using following code to work with infinite size of file:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[16 * 1024];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead =inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
   outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

I'd like to achieve the same for this Cronet API, UploadDataProvider. My plan was in its read(UploadDataSink, ByteBuffer) method, whenever this read() method was called, read ByteBuffer's limit from inputStream, but my following code not working as expected.

```
public class MyUploadDataProvider extends UploadDataProvider {

  private ReadableByteChannel byteChannel;
  MyUploadDataProvider(InputStream inputStream) {
    byteChannel = Channels.newChannel(inputStream);
  }


@Override
public void read(UploadDataSink uploadDataSink, ByteBuffer byteBuffer) throws IOException {
  boolean finalChunk = false;
  int read = this.byteChannel.read(byteBuffer); 
  if (read == -1) {
    finalChunk = true;
  }
  uploadDataSink.onReadSucceeded(finalChunk);
 }

}
```

Not sure why it read failed, can anyone please help me fix this? Thanks!

Comment: depending on what `onReadSucceeded` does, you may have to flip the buffer like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48453833/995891 - bytebuffer has a fairly diffucult to understand [api](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)

Comment: There are not clear what do you mean under **not working as expected**. Could you provide more context pls?